# How to create a custom Api in magento 2 to add multiple products in cart using single APi call?

Tags: magento2.2, rest-api

The default Api in magento 2 to add items to cart V1/carts/mine/items allows us to add only one product to cart at a time. Now I need to create a Api to add items in bulk in cart. How I can do this?

Please help. Thanks in advance.

### The Input required is somewhat like this:

```
Input - [{sku, qty, quote_id},{sku, qty, quote_id}......]
```

Comment: Please post whatever you have tried so far.

Comment: are you using magento-commerce? then you should use https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/message-queues/bulk-operations.html